# Using EHCache in JSF Web Application

Tags: jsf, ehcache

I am working on JSF application. I want to cache some database table on periodic basis. I heard EHCache does it, but I only see its use in Hibernate. Is it possible to use EHCache in JSF application or is there some alternative for that in JSF?

Comment: That does not depend on your view layer, so JSF has nothing to do with it. JSF just has to access some datasource to get some data to display. Managing such a datasource is your responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

if you want use EHCache in front end part you should write cache handler with

net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager or primefaces support now ehcache, if application is big, prefer to have 
cache handler service which put/get/check objects from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

It is your responsibility to integrate with a caching layer if none of the frameworks you use provide such an integration. You will usually do this at the service layer that computes your view objects from your stored domain objects.

Ehcache supports different [caching patterns](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/get-started/getting-started#cache-usage-patterns). And here again, picking the one that fits your use case is your responsibility.

Comment: Is there some documentation on how to configure it for an applicaton. I want caching for server side that will store authentication data. So that I can provide quick user authentication.

Comment: With such a large scope, your best starting point is the [main Ehcache documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation)